# Keep 'ser.' for series instead of its Spanish translation 'ép.'

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, spanish

I have a document in Spanish. In the bibliography, I have the following entry
[image]

I think that 'ép' is a mistranslation of 'ser.' (series).
However, I need to show 'ser.' instead of 'ép' although the rest of the bibliography must be in Spanish (for example, note that it says 'págs' to refer the pages).

The entry of the `.bib` is

```
    @book {PIE84,
        AUTHOR = {Pier, Jean-Paul},
         TITLE = {Amenable locally compact groups},
        SERIES = {Pure and Applied Mathematics (New York)},
          NOTE = {A Wiley-Interscience Publication},
     PUBLISHER = {John Wiley \& Sons, Inc., New York},
          YEAR = {1984},
         PAGES = {x+418},
          ISBN = {0-471-89390-0},
       MRCLASS = {43A07 (46N05)},
      MRNUMBER = {767264},
    MRREVIEWER = {Joseph Max Rosenblatt},
      LANGUAJE = {english},
    }
```

where LANGUAGE was my best shot (and it didn't work). My header has many lines, but these are the packages

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, open=right]{scrbook}
\sloppy
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.8cm, marginparsep=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[sorting=nty,url=false, style=ieee, doi=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{javidoc.bib}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.55cm} % Tamaño de la sangría 
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Avoid `\input xy` and `\xyoptions{all}`. With LaTeX it should be `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}`. (I recommend `cmtip`, because the default arrow tips are awful.) Avoid also `srcltx`: it's obsolete and is the cause for many pagination problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for these tips. Indeed this is the template of my advisor and it can be traced back to the 90'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ieee.bbx` has

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{series}
  {\bibstring{jourser}\addnbspace#1}
```

which looks like a slight abuse of bibstrings to me: `jourser` is obviously for journal series (new series, old series, *n*-th series) and not for book series. Indeed, there is no bibstring for book series in the `biblatex` core.

A quick fix would be

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[sorting=nty,url=false, style=ieee, doi=false]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{
  jourser = {ser\adddot},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{PIE84,
  author    = {Pier, Jean-Paul},
  title     = {Amenable locally compact groups},
  series    = {Pure and Applied Mathematics (New York)},
  publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons, Inc.},
  location  = {New York},
  year      = {1984},
  isbn      = {0-471-89390-0},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,PIE84}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: J.-P. Pier, Amenable locally compact groups, ser. Pure and Applied Mathematics (New York). New York: John Wiley & Sons, Inc., 1984, isbn: 0-471-89390-0.]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!